# Material design and Appcompat-v7 not supported in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-appcompat

I'm new to Android programming. When I tried to add material design library to
build.gradle it shows error under implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'.
Error message is :

> Dependencies using groupId `com.android.support` and `androidx.*` can not be combined but found `IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support', myArtifactId='support-fragment', myVersion='28.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'}` and `IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.arch.core', myArtifactId='core-runtime', myVersion='2.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'}` incompatible dependencies less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

I don't want to remove appcompat since I want to support lower versions.

here is my gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vignesh.materialdesigntest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: migrate to androidx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio, navigate to `Refactor` menu and select **Migrate to AndroidX**

[image: Option]

Answer (score 0):

You need to move to AndroidX

Go to android studio menu

> Refactor

under this menu 
Go to

> Migrate to AndroidX

For more information [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)

Hope it will help !

Comment: so does we have to have min Api level set to 26 now? what about support for older devices?